# Perl Undefined Error on Geo IP lookup

Tags: perl, error-handling, module, undefined

I am using [`Geo::IP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Geo::IP) to perform location lookups on ip addresses. Everything works fine until I come across an ip address which is not in the geo ip lookup database and the program shuts abruptly giving this error

```
Can't call method "city" on an undefined value at script.pl line 16.
```

Current code looks like this

```
 $gi = Geo::IP->open("/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
 my $record = $gi->record_by_addr($key);
 my $city= $record->city;
```

Any suggestions on how I can by pass this? It works perfectly fine until it hits an ip address that isn't defined within that module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Geo::IP source, if the IP address is not in the database, it returns `undef`. Therefore, to bypass the problem, you can do:

```
my $record = $gi->record_by_addr($key);
## check that $record is defined
if ($record) {
    my $city= $record->city;
    ...
}
else {
    # issue an error message if wanted
    warn "No record found for $key";
}
```

**Relevant code from the Geo::IP source:**

The function you're using is `record_by_addr`. From the source, `record_by_addr` is an alias for `get_city_record_as_hash` (see [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for the syntax used to create an 'alias' for a function):

```
*record_by_addr = \&get_city_record_as_hash;
```

The code for `get_city_record_as_hash` is as follows:

```
#this function returns the city record as a hash ref
sub get_city_record_as_hash {
  my ( $gi, $host ) = @_;
  my %gir;
  @gir{qw/ country_code   country_code3   country_name   region     city 
           postal_code    latitude        longitude      dma_code   area_code 
           continent_code region_name     metro_code / } =
    $gi->get_city_record($host);

  return defined($gir{latitude}) ? bless( \%gir, 'Geo::IP::Record' ) : undef;
}
```

This code runs `get_city_record` using `$host`, the IP address you supplied, as the argument. If `get_city_record` finds a record, the data it returns populates the `%gir` hash. The last line of the sub uses the [ternary form of if-else] to evaluate whether getting the record was successful, and to return the appropriate result. It checks whether `$gir{latitude}` is defined, and if it is, it creates and returns a `Geo::IP::Record` object from it (which you can query with methods like `city`, etc.). If it isn't, it returns `undef`.

A simpler way to view the last line would be this:

```
# is $gir{latitude} defined?
if (defined ($gir{latitude})) {
    # yes: create a Geo::IP::Record object with the data in %gir
    # return that object
    return bless( \%gir, 'Geo::IP::Record' )
}
else {
    # no: return undefined.
    return undef;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. Would you mind sharing how you figured out through the source that it returns undef. I'm pretty new to programming/scripting

Comment: I've edited the reply and added information on the source code. I hope it's relatively understandable!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you need `Data::Dumper` here, to tell you what's going on with `$record`. I would guess that `record_by_addr($key);` is the root of your problems, and that because `$key` is in some way bad, `$record` is undefined.

This would thus be fixed:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \$record;
```

I'm guessing `$record` will be undefined, and therefore:

```
next unless $record;
```

will skip it.